# Evaluate $I = \int_0^{10} \lfloor x \rfloor^3 \{x\}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate $I$:

$$I = \int_0^{10} \lfloor x \rfloor^3 \{x\}\,dx.$$

[$\{.\}$ represents the fractional part of $x$]

[ $\lfloor x \rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function / floor function of $x$]

PS- Please cite any sources that uses the proper method of evaluating floor function integrals.

I started off with re-writing $I$ as

$$I  = \int_0^{10} \lfloor x \rfloor^3 (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) \, dx,$$

which I suppose can written as

$$I =  I_1 + I_2  =  \int_0^{10} \lfloor x \rfloor^3 x  \, dx-\int_0^{10}\lfloor x \rfloor^4 \,  dx.$$

However, on evaluating $I_1$ and $I_2$ individually, I ended up the value $I = 8362.5$, which did not match with options from where I have taken this question from.

Now I believe I have made a mistake with $I_2$ on the part of writing it as $\lfloor x \rfloor^4$. It would be great to learn how to properly evaluate $I$. (or any other faster methods)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{10} {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ^3 \left\{ x \right\}{\rm d}x} & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 {\int_k^{k + 1} {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ^3 \left\{ x \right\}{\rm d}x} } = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 {\int_k^{k + 1} {k^3 \left\{ x \right\}{\rm d}x} } \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 {k^3 \int_k^{k + 1} {\left\{ x \right\}{\rm d}x} }   = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 {k^3 \frac{1}{2}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^9 {k^3 }  = \frac{{2025}}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: @user1157207 I cannot think of any source. It seemed to be the natural approach to me. The idea is that the floor function is constant between two consecutive integers. In this case if $k<x<k+1$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor  = k$. Of course I also used the additivity property of the integral.